# UIButton's addTarget not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an iOS app in Swift and I've encountered an issue with a UIButton's addTarget not working as expected. I've tried to set up a button to trigger an action, but for some reason, it's not responding to taps. I've provided my code below for reference.

```
class ErrorMessageView: UIView {
    let tryButton = UIButton()

    private lazy var buttonView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    private func configureTryButton() {
        tryButton.setTitle("Try Again", for: .normal)
        tryButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        tryButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    var buttonTapHandler: (() -> Void)?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        configureTryButton()
        setupUI()
    }

    private func setupUI() {
        buttonView.addSubview(tryButton)
        addSubview(mainStackView)
    }

    @objc private func buttonTapped() {
        buttonTapHandler?()
    }
}
```

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showErrorMessageWithTryButton(tapHandler: @escaping () -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let errorView = self.setupErrorMessageWithButton(tapHandler: tapHandler)
            self.view.addSubview(errorView)
        }
    }

    private func setupErrorMessageWithButton(tapHandler: @escaping () -> ()) -> UIView {
        let loadingView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let errorView = ErrorMessageView()
            loadingView.addSubview(errorView)
            errorView.buttonTapHandler = tapHandler
            errorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                errorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
                errorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
                errorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
                errorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.showErrorMessageWithTryButton {
            self.reloadPage()
        }
    }

    func reloadPage() {
        print("Reload Page")
    }
}
```

I've followed the standard setup for adding a target action to a UIButton, but it's still not working. Tapping the button doesn't trigger the buttonTapped function. I'm trying to call the reloadPage function in my ViewController when the button is tapped, but it's not happening.

Additional Information:

Xcode version: 14.2
iOS version/device: 16.2 / Simulator iPhone 14 Pro Max

Comment: can you check in "ErrorMessageView" instead of  "buttonView.addSubview(tryButton)" use "self.addSubview(tryButton)" and check?

Comment: it depends on your constraint and is not related to tap. I don't know what is your view that helps you add the correct constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a UIButton only receives tap events if it's not being clipped by any of the superviews.

Your `ErrorMessageView` makes no attempt to size or positions its subviews.

And in your `setupErrorMessageWithButton` method, you apply constraints to `errorView` but you fail to set a height.

Fix both of these issues so all of the views are given proper sizes and positions such that the button isn't being clipped by its superviews and the button taps should start working.

Making use of the view hierarchy debugger in Xcode will allow you to see clipped views and bad constraints.